# CSS not loading after redirecting back to homepage

Tags: css, .htaccess, redirect

first time asking a question so forgive me for any mistakes!;

I'm working on a project locally and am testing the pages. I have set a homepage using the .htaccess file:
`#Alternate default index page DirectoryIndex /en/example/example.php`

Opening the website, it correctly shows the chosen homepage on localhost:8888 and correctly loads the css, all good.

From here, I click through to a second page which loads different css, all works well. This page  automatically prompts a modal window with a button, which I've set to link back to the homepage, using:
`<a href="/en/example/example.php">Back</a>`

Now, when testing this button, it does redirect back to "localhost:8888/en/example/example.php", text shows but css is not being loaded in now, nothing at all.

Could anybody shine a light on why suddenly it does not load in the css anymore?
Thanks a lot, please let me know if I should share any other info...

Comment: How do you declare css? Put piece of code please

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/assets/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">